# LDAP authentication with AD LDP from Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-boot, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to implement LDAP authentication in a Sprint Boot application.  In the test environment I have installed an Active Directory LDP service with which to authenticate.  I have created a user within the AD instance, enabled the account and set a password.  I am then trying to authenticate using this account from the Spring login form.

When I try to log in using AD I get an error message:

> Your login attempt was not successful, try again.
>
> Reason: Bad credentials

As I am new to both AD and Spring it is quite possible I have mis-configured either (or both!).

**Do you have any suggestions as to how I can further diagnose this problem or is there anything obvious I may have missed?**

My Spring Boot code (I have tried a number of different variations on this code, this is one example):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = 
                new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("foo.bar", "ldap://servername:389");
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there was nothing wrong with my Java implementation.  The issue appears to be with the AD LDP configuration.  I tried connecting to another, known good instance of AD LDP and authentication worked first time.

I am going to mark this as the answer as I am no longer interested in a solution to this question and wish to close it down...