# Spring Boot + AD Authentication - No XML config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap

After a day long searching and trying, I'm still unable to get Spring Security working with Active Directory.

So facts:

- Spring Boot 2.1.0-RELEASE
- JVM 1.8.181
- I definitely want to avoid the security XML config

I'm building a MVC app (single war), and need an AD AuthN. Later AuthZ as well in order to distinguish roles.

I do not want to bother with reviewing my code, but I have followed this example:

[LDAP authentication with AD LDP from Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572299/ldap-authentication-with-ad-ldp-from-spring-boot-application)

The last comment says it works and most of the examples are varieties of the example above (the process flow is the same), but I'm still getting this message:

> LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042F, comment: >AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580

Is there any tutorial, or simply things explained to get this working? My credentials are 100% correct and unlocked. Tested with Apache Directory Studio.

Our AD users are under OU=OU_Users,DC=company,DC=com

Thanks a lot!

BR,
Pavel

Answer (score 0):

There are two issue related to your question already on stackoverflow please find here:

[LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31411665/ldap-error-code-49-80090308-ldaperr-dsid-0c0903a9-comment-acceptsecurityc)

[: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 773, v1db1 ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112130/ldap-error-code-49-80090308-ldaperr-dsid-0c0903a9-comment-acceptsecuri)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Khwaya, it explains the error itself. The weird fact is it is working now, and i'm not sure what exactly has made it working... I'll post the result after analysis :-)